# Editing bash commands?

Tags: bash, shell, putty

I use "Putty Connection Manager" in Windows, and I was wondering how to do the following.

Often, I find myself editing larger bash commands that have many characters on a single line; nested loops, etc...which are quite long!  While I often make use of the "Home" and "End" keys to go to the beginning and end of my line, I'd like a more efficient way to move through the line than simply pressing the Right and Left arrow keys.

`vi`, for instance, can move forward "by word" if you press the `w` key (which moves you all the way to the next word)

I'd like to do something similar in a bash shell.  Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the emacs keybindings with bash (I believe that's the default) try using M-f and M-b to move forward and back words where M is the "Meta" key, probably Alt for you.  You can also use C-a (ctrl+a) and C-e to jump to the beginning of lines, even though it seems you already have keys for that. Alt+bksp is also handy to delete whole words.

Answer (score 1):

In fact yes, you can run

```
set -o vi
```

to turn on the vi editing mode. Like in regular vi, you have command-mode and insert-mode; unlike in regular vi, insert-mode is the default.

There's a nice cheat-sheet here: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/